# foreach loop inside caml query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I have a list of Employee class which has empid and empname as property.

Now I want to construct a caml query IN clause where list column id in empid.

How can I write a foreach loop inside caml query and set each id in  tag?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the SharePoint version as this is important for the available features of the CAML syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which programming language you are using nor which version of SharePoint (2007, 20010, etc). But here is an example in C#. You should also check out Camlex.NET as Alex suggested. Here is a possible example for you, though:

```
    StringBuilder queryText = new StringBuilder(@"<Where><In><FieldRef Name = 'ID'/><Values>");
    foreach (var person in MyPeopleCollection)
    {
        queryText.Append(@"<Value Type = 'Number'/>");
        queryText.Append(person.Id);
        queryText.Append("</Values>");
    }
    queryText.Append(@"</In></Where>");
    SPListItemCollection Items = MyList.GetItems(new SPQuery(){QueryStringValueProvider = queryText });
```

Comment: Thanks Robert very much.Exactly same thing I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Camlex.NET](http://camlex.codeplex.com/).

Camlex.NET simplifies creating of CAML queries for SharePoint by using expression. 
So you can easily construct a CAML query.
Try it.